# Not able to launch juypter on anaconda-nag on mac m1 chip

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am new here and still learning Pip and python is installed, the $path has anaconda in it. The error doesnot show which package has a problem. when I copy the URL on google it opens yet on the prompt or the anaconda-nagivator it doesnot open. Any clue?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: when I click launch juypter from anaconda-navigator I get the message in the snapshot and doesnot open. If I copy the URL like http://localhost:8888/tree to google it opens. Not sure what's wrong?

Comment: If I type this in python it opens, but not from the anaconda navigator webbrowser.open('http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=e8694ca4d8133007e7d1c6dd0afecf3a533957d61048685a')
True